# PDF annotations in Java

Tags: java, pdf, icepdf

Actually, still now I have not got the exact way to add different types of annotation/lines/boxes/highlights using the mouse directly on PDF.

I have tried different API (pdfbox, icepdf, iText, aspose) and successfully able to add text, text annotation, box annotation, images, but for each one i have some issue like:

- when i add object, it add in a new page
- when i add object it remove the old data
- i want use the existing ICEPDF viewer to add text, but it does not allow it. and if i try to mix other API with ICEPDF, then I am not able to get the mouse click position where need to add.

There is only one API (ICE PDF) which allow to add box annotation direct on GUI by mouse but it does allow other things.

If not possible in pdf viewer then is there any class which will allow to do this?

I'm also open for any commercial library/class with a one time fee to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think BFO have added quite a few annotation tools. Have you looked at their tool?

Comment: Yes, bfo.faceless.pdf2 library has many features... have a look at that once. [Click here](http://bfo.com/products/pdf/docs/api/org/faceless/pdf2/PDF.html)